# Polling a specific file name from local to FTP server

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I want to send a specific file from a local folder to FTP, this folder contains different csv files, I only want to send a specific one. Here is the code I'm using but this is sending all the CSV files in this folder, how can I make it to look if there is this specific file for example "foo.csv" , if it is there then send it to FTP

```
public IntegrationFlow localToFtpFlow(Branch myBranch){
        return IntegrationFlows.from(Files.inboundAdapter(new File(myBranch.getBranchCode()))//.patternFilter("final" + myBranch.getBranchCode() +".csv")
                    .filter(new ChainFileListFilter<File>()
                            .addFilter(new RegexPatternFileListFilter("final" + myBranch.getBranchCode() +".csv"))
                            .addFilter(new FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter(new SimpleMetadataStore(), "foo"))),
                        //.filter(new FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter(new SimpleMetadataStore(), "foo")),
                e -> e.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(10_000)))

                .log()
                .handle(Ftp.outboundAdapter(createNewFtpSessionFactory(myBranch), FileExistsMode.REPLACE)
                        .useTemporaryFileName(true)
                        .autoCreateDirectory(true)
                        .remoteDirectory(myBranch.getFolderPath()))
                .get();
    }
```

I tried adding patterfilter or regexfilter as shown below but I got the an error.

```
IntegrationFlows.from(Files.inboundAdapter(new File(myBranch.getBranchCode())).patternFilter("final" + myBranch.getBranchCode() +".csv")
```

Error when running.

```
The 'filter' reference is mutually exclusive with either the 'filename-pattern' or 'filename-regex' attribute.
```

Tried to search for a solution but could not get a clear one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you need to configure several filters on the `Files.inboundAdapter()`, you need to consider to use a `CompositeFileListFilter` or `ChainFileListFilter`. Compose your `ChainFileListFilter` and `SimplePatternFileListFilter` into that one and inject a composite filter into that `.filter()` option.

The `.patternFilter()` and `.regexFilter()` are there for convenience and they are really mutually exclusive with the `.filter()`.

See more info about composition in the Docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/files.html#file-reading

Comment: i updated the flow to use ChainfilelistFilter as requested it seems working smoothly after few trials, please confirm to me that this is the way should be done in my code...I'm accepting the answer as well@Artem Bilan

Comment: Yes, that’s great solution!